# How to send OTLP metrics data from node.js to Rust grpc server

Tags: node.js, rust, open-telemetry

Using this particular proto file given below
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto/blob/main/opentelemetry/proto/metrics/v1/metrics.proto
I have created a grpc server in Rust and implemented the export method like this :

```
impl MetricsService for MyMetrics {
    async fn export(
        &self,
        request: Request<ExportMetricsServiceRequest>,
    ) -> Result<Response<ExportMetricsServiceResponse>, Status> {
        println!("Got a request from {:?}", request.remote_addr());
        println!("request data ==> {:?}", request);


        let reply = metrics::ExportMetricsServiceResponse {};
        Ok(Response::new(reply))
    }
}
```

To test this code,

1. I created a grpc client in node.js with same proto file and called the export method - which worked as expected.

---

2. Then, I used otlpmetricsexporter in node.js (instead of making an explicit call to export method), in this case, I am not receiving the request on Rust grpc server.

Getting this error :
`{"stack":"Error: 12 UNIMPLEMENTED: \n at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/home/acq053/work/src/github.com/middleware-labs/agent-node-metrics/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)\n at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/acq053/work/src/github.com/middleware-labs/agent-node-metrics/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:189:52)\n at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/acq053/work/src/github.com/middleware-labs/agent-node-metrics/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:365:141)\n at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/acq053/work/src/github.com/middleware-labs/agent-node-metrics/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:328:181)\n at /home/acq053/work/src/github.com/middleware-labs/agent-node-metrics/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:187:78\n at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)","message":"12 UNIMPLEMENTED: ","code":"12","metadata":"[object Object]","name":"Error"}`

My Rust Grpc server is running @ [::1]:50057
so, I used OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=[::1]:50057 env while running my node.js exporter

What could have gone wrong ?!

_
https://github.com/Bhogayata-Keval/rust-grpc-demo.git

Comment: hello, wich crate you use? could you show your Cargo.toml or provide a minimal code to test this issue?

Comment: @Zeppi added git repo (rust code)

Answer (score 1):

I compile your code with 2 changes.

1. remove `tonic_build::compile_protos("proto/helloworld.proto")`in buld.rs
2. update `let addr = "[::1]:50057".parse().unwrap();` by `let addr = "127.0.0.1:50057".parse().unwrap();` in metric.rs.

I ran target/debug/metrics. and I used, [grpcurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) like client. With the command

```
./grpcurl -plaintext -import-path ./proto -proto metrics.proto 127.0.0.1:50057 metrics.MetricsService/Export
```

And result was

```
{

}
```

It is the expected result?

Regards

Comment: Yes, the response is fine, as I have just returned ExportMetricsServiceResponse. As the code worked for you with grpccurl, the same way it worked with node.js grpc client. Now, the issue is if I use otlpexporter (which is also apperantly a grpc client), it does not call this export method and thus does not return `{ }`

Comment: The query is more about comparing OTLP exporter with grpc client. Does otlp exporter also call the export method on grpc server ?! or does it expect something more ?!

Comment: From what I understand, the OTLP is implemented over grpc. So you can be inspired by https://crates.io/crates/opentelemetry-otlp

Comment: Actually, I have been using this crate for a while now, but it only contains the exporter support. There is no implementation of receiver in this crate

Comment: I don't know OpenTelemetry well and just for my understanding. According to this [demo](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/examples/demo), if I understand correctly you tried to write the otel-collector component. Right?